# Trying to solve this inequality for a collection of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_n\}$ be a collection of non-empty sets (meaning $A_i's$ are non-empty sets).

$\textbf{Step 1}$

Find $A_i,A_j\in\mathcal{F}\ (i\neq j)$ such that $A_i\cap A_j\neq\emptyset$

$\textbf{Step 2}$

Redefine $\mathcal{F}$ as
$$\mathcal{F}=(\mathcal{F}\setminus\{A_i,A_j\})\cup \{A_i\setminus A_j,\,A_j\setminus A_i,\,A_i\cap A_j\} .$$

$\textbf{Step 3}$

$\textbf{Check if}$ $\forall A_i,A_j\in\mathcal{F} (i\neq j)$ we have $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$, then set $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{F}$,

$\textbf{Otherwise}$ go back on $\textbf{Step 1}$, $\textbf{Step 2}$ and $\textbf{Step 3}$

$\textbf{ Now I am trying to prove mathematically:}$

$$|\mathcal{D}|\leq 2^n-1.$$

Any lead about how it can be proved mathematically?

Comment: @AnneBauval ; yes, $A_i\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Hint: Consider an element $x$ in the union of the $A_i$. it will be contained in the $A_i$'s in some $\mathcal{F}_x\subseteq \mathcal{F}$. There are $2^n-1$ subsets of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @Math_Images_Only ; I couldn't get you. Can you write a detailed answer to this question?

Comment: sorry wrong question

Comment: @Math_Images_Only ; Did you mean my question is wrong?

Comment: No I posted an answer to the wrong question. I will try to answer your question but it will take a bit

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you know that $\vert \mathcal{P}(A)\vert=2^{\vert A\vert}$. We assume that $A_i\neq \emptyset$ and I prove the theorem by induction on $\vert \mathcal{F}\vert=n$. The case in which $\mathcal{F}$ has one element is trivial and so is the case in which $\mathcal{F}$ is empty. Now assume that the theorem holds for all collections of $n$ elements and let $\mathcal{F}=\{A_1,\dots, A_{n+1}\}$ now I apply the induction hypothesis to the first $n$ elements $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ so by applying the steps $1$ to $3$ to this family of sets I get at most $2^n-1$ disjoint sets $B_1,\dots, B_k$ where $k\leq 2^n-1$. So we have that after applying such steps to $\mathcal{F}$ we have it will be of the form $\mathcal{F}=\{B_1,\dots,B_k,A_{n+1}\}$. Using the fact that the $B_j$ are all disjoint if I re apply the steps to $\mathcal{F}$ I get
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}=\{B_1\setminus A_{n+1},B_1\cap A_{n+1},\dots, B_k\setminus A_{n+1}, B_1\cap A_{n+1}, A_{n+1}\setminus(B_1\cup\dots \cup B_k)\}
\end{equation*}
Meaning for each $i\leq k$ $\mathcal{F}$ contains $B_i\setminus A_{n+1}$ and $B_i\cap A_{n+1}$ and it will also contain the set $A_{n+1}\setminus(B_1\cup\dots \cup B_k)$. Some of these sets might be empty it doesn't matter what matters is at this point all the sets are pairwise disjoint and there can be no more than $2k+1\leq 2(2^n-1)+1=2^{n+1}-1$. I'm willing to add more details if needed.

Comment: The algorithm does not allow you to isolate $n$ subsets out of $n+1$ and handle them separately beforehand. It executes step 1 without asking you your prefered pair $(i,j)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval it does not specify the order in which the $A_i$'s are handled so I supposed it was arbitrary

Comment: What I read makes me suppose it is arbitrarily chosen by the machine, not by us. Anyway, it is a harder (hence more interesting?) problem.

Comment: I think one would just have to show that if the I apply  the steps in different order it will yield the same sets. I will add this in a bit @AnneBauval

Comment: @Math_Images_Only ; Your answer was close, but as Anne Bauval has pointed out, you do not have preferences for $A_i's$.

Comment: @AnneBauval ; I wonder if this problem is NP-hard?

Comment: @Robin I can't even imagine what this could mean, and I am confident he (or me?) will find a more accurate answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval ; I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal G$ be the collection of sets of the form $\cup_{i=1}^nX_i$ where each $X_j$ is equal to either $A_j$ or $A_j^c$ (the complement set of $A_j$ in $\cup_{i=1}^nA_i$) and at least one of them is $A_j$. (These sets are pairwise disjoint but some of them may be empty.)

By induction, at each loop, any $A_i\in\mathcal F$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal G$.

Let $\mathcal D=\{B_1,\dots,B_d\}$ be the final collection of $d$ non-empty paiwise disjoint sets. Since the $B_j$'s are non-empty, we may choose, for each $j=1,\dots,d$, a non-empty $C_j\in\mathcal G$ such that $C_j\subset B_j$. And since the $B_j$'s are disjoint, the $C_j$'s are distinct.

Hence
$$|\mathcal D|=d\le|\mathcal G|\le 2^n-1.$$

Comment: Dear Anne, I am not able to understand your answer. (1) Since, $|\mathcal{G}^{'}|=2^n-1$ and $\{E_1,...,E_d\}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{G}^{'}$, so, we must have $d\mid 2^n-1$. How would you show that indeed $d\mid 2^n-1$? As a counter-example, let $\mathcal{F}=\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$ such that $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset,\ A_1\cap A_3=\emptyset,\  A_2\cap A_3\neq \emptyset$. Then $\mathcal{D}=\{A_1, A_2\setminus A_3, A_2\cap A_3, A_3\setminus A_2\}$, but $4\nmid 7$.  (2) How are you able to see $B_j=\cup_{(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)\in E_j}X_1\cap X_2\cap...\cap X_n$? Can you write your answer in more detail?

Comment: Dear Robin, (1) we must not have $d\mid 2^n-1$, only $d\le 2^n-1$ (look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). (2) I am intuitively convinced of the existence of such a partition but unable for the moment to write a rigorous proof of it.

Comment: Ok, whenever you find the time please post a rigorous proof.